# Import .txt file to SQL database using VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a SQL database (local using vb.net) which has a table with 76 columns. The data that needs to be put into those columns is in the form of a plain delimited text file. I need to build a VB.NET application which will allow me to import the text file into the table in the database under their appropriate columns. Is there any way I can do this?

I'm very new to VB.NET. Can someone help me out with the code?

Thank You!
Kamall

Answer (score 1):

If you have comma-separated values:

```
bulk insert tableName
from 'C:\myfile.txt'
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n')
go
```

For tab-separated values use:

```
bulk insert tableName
from 'C:\myfile.txt'
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n')
go
```

Comment: To clarify this is not VB.Net, it's T-SQL, and personally I think it's a much more simpler and effective solution

Comment: Why even bother with VB.Net it's just complicating it if you ask me.

Comment: Reason is, we are building a front-end application using vb.net and this application would help us in importing and manipulation the data from the underlying database

Comment: Really @Nick.McDermaid? @Kamall I need to know how familiar you are with database connectivity in VB.NET. Do you know how to establish a database connection with .NET code?

Comment: yes @marttronix, I was able to create a local DB and establish a connection to it using vb.net

Comment: Dim query As String = "bulk insert tablename from 'c:\myfile.txt' with(fieldterminator=',',rowterminator='\n')"
Command = New SqlCommand(query, connection)
command.ExecuteReader()

Comment: Now that the OP has provided more information about his purposes, its clear that an application does need to be built.

Answer (score 0):

76 columns ? 
Must be the god-table antipattern ...

```
   Public Sub CopyToDataBase(dt As DataTable)

    Using Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING")
        Conn.Open()

        Using s As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(Conn)

            s.DestinationTableName = "TableName"
            s.WriteToServer(dt)
            s.Close()

        End Using

        Conn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

of course this requires the table to have a primary key.